# MS Teams Adaptive Cards links to channels not triggering "join team" workflow when you're not a member

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, microsoft-graph-teams

We have a workflow in MS Teams where we link a large group of users directly to channel that lives in a different MS Teams "team" object from which we're sending the link.  Most users that would click the link are members of the other team but there are increasingly more common occasions where this is not the case.  The links are posted programmatically through the Graph API within an Adaptive card.  The experience for the user is extremely inconsistent depending on how the link is posted.  Our desired behavior would be, if the user is not a member of the team, regardless of how they are linked or which platform they're on (mobile, desktop, web client), they will be pushed into the "join team" workflow where they can click the "join" button within their MS Teams client and be brought directly to the desired channel.  These are public teams and public channels, by the way.

When the users are members of the destination team, everything seems to work just fine.  This is only a problem when the users are not members of the destination team object.

Brief summary of the current behavior for a user that **IS NOT** a member of the destination team...

**Action.OpenUrl button in the adaptive card...**
 - Mobile Client -- redirects to a page saying "you are no longer a member of this team".  Important to note this was not the behavior for us just two days ago.  Unclear why this changed but user's used to be redirected to the "join team" workflow which is expected behavior.
 - Windows Desktop Client -- redirects the user back the "General" channel of whatever team is first in their desktop client.  This behavior is not at all comprehensive and confuses people so much.

**HTML link within an adaptive card**
 - Mobile Client -- redirects to a page saying "you are no longer a member of this team".  Important to note this was not the behavior for us just two days ago.  Unclear why this changed but user's used to be redirected to the "join team" workflow which is expected behavior.
 - Windows Desktop Client -- redirects to the user's default web browser outside of the client (Chrome in my case) and asks the user if they want to use the desktop client or the web browser to open the link.  Regardless of the option that's selected, the user is pushed into the "join team" workflow which is better but still really bad.

**Full link posted in the same message as the adaptive card but is not contained within the adaptive card container**
 - Mobile Client -- redirects to a page saying "you are no longer a member of this team".  Important to note this was not the behavior for us just two days ago.  Unclear why this changed but user's used to be redirected to the "join team" workflow which is expected behavior.
 - Desktop Client -- redirect the user to the "join team" workflow, this is the desired behavior but clearly it's inconsistent depending if the user is on mobile or within the desktop client when they click the link

More detail can be found on this github page:
https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/3338

I need a consistent user experience, regardless of which platform a user is on.  My question for the community is, how can I best accomplish this?  I'm disappointed the mobile client doesn't seem to redirect our channel links to the "join team" workflow at all currently.  I have no idea why this behavior changed.  The github page mentions using "deep links" as a possibility.  I have no doubt Microsoft will clean this up at some point but the lack of consistency is driving disengagement for our technical teams, most of whom are used to using Slack where all links just work.

Comment: Could you please share some screenshots of the differences you see in Desktop vs Mobile?

Comment: Of course, I will send some screenshots.  So, I was able to narrow down this behavior a bit today and can consistently replicate it.

To replicate... 
1.  Have someone post a link to a channel for a team that you're not apart of.
2.  On mobile, click the link, you should be pushed into the "join team" workflow
3.  Join the team by clicking "join"
4.  Chat with your friends/team a bit, leave the team
5.  On mobile, go back to the original link and click it.  You are presented with "you are no longer a member of the team" message.

Comment: PLease attach some screenshots so that i can raise a bug for this.